# Quarkus: Discovered unresolved type during parsing: io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl while building native-image

Tags: java, spring, quarkus, graalvm

I'm trying to migrate a SpringBoot project to Quarkus. When I try to build a native image with Graal VM, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved type during parsing: io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl. To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing type is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.reportUnresolvedElement(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:286)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.handleUnresolvedType(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:242)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.handleUnresolvedNewInstance(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:186)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genNewInstance(BytecodeParser.java:4619)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genNewInstance(BytecodeParser.java:4612)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBytecode(BytecodeParser.java:5409)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3436)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3243)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.build(BytecodeParser.java:1109)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.buildRootMethod(BytecodeParser.java:1003)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.GraphBuilderPhase$Instance.run(GraphBuilderPhase.java:84)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase.run(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:76)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.run(Phase.java:49)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.BasePhase.apply(BasePhase.java:212)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:42)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:38)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.parse(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:223)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.apply(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:357)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.doParse(MethodTypeFlow.java:313)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.ensureParsed(MethodTypeFlow.java:302)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.addContext(MethodTypeFlow.java:103)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.StaticInvokeTypeFlow.update(InvokeTypeFlow.java:434)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.BigBang$2.run(BigBang.java:547)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(CompletionExecutor.java:173)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
        ... 5 more
```

My project uses quarkus-resteasy and I'm trying to build my native image with GraalVM CE 21.0.0.2 (build 11.0.10+8-jvmci-21.0-b06, mixed mode, sharing).
The application can be viewed here: https://gitlab.com/henixdevelopment/open-source/opentestfactory/java-plugins/-/tree/26-perf-study-replace-springboot-by-quarkus
The service I'm trying to build is otf-robot-framework-interpreter.
Has anyone encountered this error before?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Any chance we can see your application?

Comment: Sure ! The application can be viewed here: https://gitlab.com/henixdevelopment/open-source/opentestfactory/java-plugins/-/tree/26-perf-study-replace-springboot-by-quarkus The service I'm trying to build is otf-robot-framework-interpreter.

Comment: Can't really tell what the problem is unfortunately